# how to hide markers from DirectionsService's DirectionsRoute object in google maps api v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In google maps api v3, I think you can no longer get all the markers on the map object. I need to hide the very last marker from the DirectionsService result. I used to be able to do this in v2:

_gdir.getMarker(_gdir.getNumRoutes()).hide();

I have routes that start and end in the same place, and I need to hide the very last marker so that it does not overlay my original origin maker.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can settle with hiding all of them then the DirectionsRendererOptions has an option to suppress markers.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions

Answer (score 0):

You hide/remove a marker using the `setMap()` method with `null` as the argument:

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

Check google docs [Remove Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#remove). Note that the above method does not delete the marker. It simply hide/removes the marker from the map. If you want to show it again just use:

```
marker.setMap(map);
```